# Subtraction of 2 times in the format minutes : seconds : centiseconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, time

I am trying to write code which subtracts a time B from a time A (time A - time B), both in the format minutes : seconds : centiseconds.  How can this be achieved in Javascript?  I currently have the code below.  One can assume that that time A will always be later than time B.

```
let minDiff = minutes - temp[temp.length - 1].timestamp[0]
      if(temp[temp.length - 1].timestamp[1] > seconds){
        let minDiff = minDiff-1;
        let secondsDiff = seconds + Math.abs(seconds - temp[temp.length - 1].timestamp[1])
      }
      if(temp[temp.length - 1].timestamp[2] > ms){}
```

Comment: Here's how I'd do it ... convert the times to a number of centiseconds ... subtract one from the other ... convert the result to minutes:seconds:centiseconds

Comment: (1) Convert both strings to a common base integer unit which has higher precision than either (milliseconds is native in JavaScript). (2) Subtract. (3) Convert the result back to your preferred format if desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution - by converting "min:sec:cs" to an integer number of total centiseconds, the maths is easy - after that you convert back to "min:sec:cs" format

```js
const timeA = "2:34:56"
const timeB = "1:54:32"

const mscToC = str => str.split(':').map(Number).reduce((a, b, i) => a * (i < 2 ? 60 : 100) + b);
const cToMsc = n => {
  const f2 = n => n.toString().padStart(2, 0);
  const c = n % 100;
  n = (n - c) / 100;
  const s = n % 60;
  const m = (n - s) / 60;
  return `${m}:${f2(s)}:${f2(c)}`;
}

const result = cToMsc(mscToC(timeA) - mscToC(timeB));
console.log(result);
```